# Webpack 5 module federation error handling

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I've a micro frontends running on monorepo using nx CLI where in the host application I'm using module federation to get the remoteEntry.js files from all the micro frontends and serve them as components per route.

I've error boundary which works perfect on dev / staging / production environment and displays 404 page when the remoteEntry is not fetched / crashed for some reason and it works as expected.

But when I want to run unit tests on the shell application to test its functionality and I'm running only the shell application, for some reason I'm receiving errors from webpack saying the following:

**Loading script failed.
(error: http://localhost:3107/remoteEntry.js)**

Which is expected, because I didn't run any of the micro frontends.

What I want to achieve is that I will be able to run only the shell application locally and get the 404 page also on local without having this error, in other words - I want to handle the errors when the micro frontends are not live.

Any suggestions how can I achieve that?

webpack file on the shell application:

```
const nrwlConfig = require('@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack.js');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const deps = require('../../package.json').dependencies;
const { remoteEntries } = require('./remoteEntries');

const EnvType = {
  LOCAL: 'local',
  PLAYGROUND: 'playground',
  DEVELOPMENT: 'development',
  STAGING: 'staging',
  PRODUCTION: 'production',
};

module.exports = (config) => {
  nrwlConfig(config);

  config.optimization.runtimeChunk = 'single';

  return {
    ...config,
    plugins: [
      ...config.plugins,
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'hostApp',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        remotes: {
          app1: `app1@${getRemoteEntryUrl(remoteEntries.APP1)}`,
          app2: `app2@${getRemoteEntryUrl(remoteEntries.APP2)}`,
          app3: `app3@${getRemoteEntryUrl(
            remoteEntries.APP3
          )}`,
          app4: `app4@${getRemoteEntryUrl(
            remoteEntries.APP4
          )}`,
          app5: `app5@${getRemoteEntryUrl(remoteEntries.APP5)}`,
          app6: `app6@${getRemoteEntryUrl(
            remoteEntries.APP6
          )}`,
          app7: `app7@${getRemoteEntryUrl(
            remoteEntries.APP7
          )}`,
        },
        shared: {
          ...deps,
          react: {
            singleton: true,
            eager: true,
            requiredVersion: deps.react,
          },
          'react-dom': {
            singleton: true,
            eager: true,
            requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  };
};

const getRemoteEntryUrl = (entry) => {
  const { NODE_ENV } = process.env || EnvType.DEVELOPMENT;

  if (NODE_ENV !== EnvType.LOCAL) {
    return entry.remoteEntries[NODE_ENV];
  }

  return `http://localhost:${entry.localPort}/remoteEntry.js`;
};
```